# how to convert svg path to glyph path code

Tags: javascript, svg, glyph

I have this type of icons in my website

`<glyph unicode="&#xe908;" glyph-name="fb" horiz-adv-x="532" d="M531.692 789.858h-96.886c-78.769 0-89.797-36.234-89.797-89.009v-115.791h180.382l-23.631-181.957h-157.538v-467.102h-186.683v467.102h-157.538v181.957h157.538v134.695c-0.652 6.351-1.023 13.724-1.023 21.183 0 121.373 98.393 219.766 219.766 219.766 6.182 0 12.305-0.255 18.358-0.756 1.311 0.066 3.801 0.074 6.293 0.074 46.065 0 91.527-2.583 136.248-7.611z" />`

I am trying to add more icons but my icons are SVG, my website accept glyph path, so I have to convert my svg to glyph

Standrad SVG path is not working

Comment: That seems to be the [`<glyph>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/fonts.html#GlyphElement) element that the SVG 1.1 specification defines. It is not supported directly by any browser, so I suspect you are using a library for interpretation. The `d` attribute contains the same path microsyntax as the `<path>` element. The only significant difference is that the coordinate system is upside-down, with the origin **at the bottom** and the y axis pointing **up**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696217/convert-glyph-path-to-svg

Comment: You can also convert svg fonts to svg icons via [fontello](https://fontello.com) or [icomoon](https://icomoon.io) web apps and vice versa. But It's more likely you actually see a woff2,woff or truetype icon font – since svg fonts are only supported by some webkit browsers (e.g apple safari). Chromium browsers and Firefox has removed support for svg fonts years ago.

Comment: actually i find that  that icons are generated with icomoon in my website, its wordpress website
but i can not find solutions to add more icons 
I am trying to add svg path to glyph d="" but its shows nothing

Comment: As mentioned before: the **svg icon font is most certainly not used for rendering** (but the woff2 or woff).  But you can use this file as an **import format for icomoon** as explained here ["How to include a new glyph icon in already existing list from IconMoon?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856818/how-to-include-a-new-glyph-icon-in-already-existing-list-from-iconmoon/72859591#72859591). After importing the existent icon font, you can import new icons as single standard svg files (i.e not using `<glyph>`).  After defining tweaking size etc. you can generate a new icon font.